# What do all the blade options do?

Tags: laravel-4, templating, laravel-blade

Looking at the laravel blade source code, I see there appear to be a lot of different commands, like `@show`, `@append`, or `@endunless`, that don't appear in the official laravel docs. Can someone give me a list of all the `@-` options in blade, and what they do?

Answer (score 0):

You could try digging around in the online API docs and see if that yields the answers you're looking for. Possibly some of them are internal methods?

[Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.View.Compilers.BladeCompiler.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, `Compile Blade show statements into valid PHP.` does not tell me WHAT php it is being compiled into.

Comment: I know, I was just suggesting the online API as a place to go digging for info